# Javascript in Ajax load Page not working

Tags: ajax, popup, modal-dialog

We have developed form creation module like Google Forms in PHP.. all is working fine while adding & creating the form..

For Editing, we have used modal popup for which we are loading content using Ajax..

**MAIN.PHP**

```
$('a[data-toggle=modal]').click(function(){

  var qid = $(this).attr('data-id');
   $.ajax({
      type : 'post',
       url : 'URL.php', // in here you should put your query 
      data :  'post_id='+ qid, // here you pass your id via ajax .
                 // in php you should use $_POST['post_id'] to get this value 
   success : function(r)
       {
          // now you can show output in your modal 
          $('#mymodal').show();  // put your modal id 
         $('.something').show().html(r);
       }
        });
    });
```

**URL.PHP :**

```
$(document).on(function(){
    $("#question_type2").change(function(){
    alert("hello");
        $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="text2"){
                $(".box2").hide();
                $(".text2").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="textarea2"){
                $(".box2").hide();
                $(".textarea2").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="radio2"){
                $(".box2").hide();
                $(".radio2").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="checkbox2"){
                $(".box2").hide();
                $(".checkbox2").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="dropdown2"){
                $(".box2").hide();
                $(".dropdown2").show();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});


 <table id="dataTable1" class="form">
 <input type="hidden" name="question_id2" value="<?php echo $qid; ?>">
     <tr>
         <td>Question Title</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="question_title2" id="question_title2" value="<?php echo
 $row_question2['question_title']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Question Type</td>
    <td>

        <select id="question_type2" name="question_type2">
            <option value="text2" <?php if($row_question2["question_type"]=='text'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>Text</option>
            <option value="textarea2" <?php if($row_question2["question_type"]=='textarea'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>Paragraph</option>
            <option value="radio2" name="radio" <?php if($row_question2["question_type"]=='radio'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>Multiple Choice</option>
            <option value="checkbox2" name="checkbox" <?php if($row_question2["question_type"]=='checkbox'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>Checkbox</option>
            <option value="dropdown2" <?php if($row_question2["question_type"]=='dropdown'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>Dropdown Selection</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <div class="text2 box2">
            <input type="text" name="text_ans" placeholder="Their Answer" readonly>
        </div>

        <div class="textarea2 box2">
            <textarea name="textarea_ans" rows="3" cols="20" placeholder="Their Long Answer" readonly></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="radio2 box2" id="fieldadd_radio2">
        <?php
            $multiple_radio=explode(",",$row_question2['question_value']);
            foreach($multiple_radio as $radio)
            {
        ?>
            <input type="text" name="radio[]" id="radio" value="<?php echo $radio; ?>" >
        <?php
            }
        ?>
            <input type="button" value="Add More Option" onclick="mplfile_radio2()" />
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox2 box2" id="fieldadd_checkbox2">
        <?php 
            $multiple_checkbox=explode(",",$row_question2['question_value']);
            foreach($multiple_checkbox as $checkbox)
            {
        ?>
            <input type="text" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox" value="<?php echo $checkbox; ?>" >
        <?php
            }
        ?>
            <input type="button" value="Add More Option" onclick="mplfile_checkbox2()" />
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown2 box2" id="fieldadd_dropdown2">
        <?php 
            $multiple_dropdown=explode(",",$row_question2['question_value']);
            foreach($multiple_dropdown as $dropdown)
            {
        ?>
            <input type="text" name="dropdown[]" id="dropdown" value="<?php echo $dropdown; ?>" >
        <?php
            }
        ?>
            <input type="button" value="Add More Option" onclick="mplfile_dropdown2()" />
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
 </table>
```

**ISSUE :**

in url.php, the javascript for show & hide of div is not working while calling it through modal popu in Main.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done...

issue is been resolved using java script conflict